# How to keep all the elements on top when hover

Tags: html, css

I divided the screen in 4 parts

```
#left {
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
height: calc(100vh - 100px);
width: 25%;
cursor: url(img/extra/cursors/left.png), auto;
z-index: 10003;
}

#right {
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
right: 50px;
height: calc(100vh - 100px);
width: 25%;
cursor: url(img/extra/cursors/right.png), auto;
z-index: 10003;
}

#up {
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
height: 25%;
width: calc(100% - 100px);
cursor: url(img/extra/cursors/up.png), auto;
z-index: 10003;
}

#down {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
left: 50px;
height: 25%;
width: calc(100% - 100px);
cursor: url(img/extra/cursors/down.png), auto;
z-index: 10003;
```

}

When you :hover each part, the cursor will become an arrow and when you click you can surf the page up / left / down / right.

My concern is that I would love to have all the upper part of the screen covered by the #up, all the bottom by the #down, all the left by the #left and all the right by the #right. I would love to avoid the overlap of the divs in the corners of the screen.

Not so easy to explain: have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LswbL5qL/

Comment: Might be easier to convert to JavaScript and do calculations based on cursor position compared to window height/width.

Comment: Thanks @SetSailMedia I'm too newbie to code something like that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood you right, but here is my solution anyway =))

1. Remove those crazy `z-index`. 10003 is too much. Something like 5 is enough
2. You need to boost z-index on hover, so add

   ```
   div:hover {
     z-index: 10 !important
   }
   ```

to your CSS. After that once you hover over any div - it will become "main" to others and same for others. Hope it's exactly what you was looking for

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks so much @Paradoxetion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon id="up" points="0,0 50,50 100,0"/>
  <polygon id="left" points="0,0 50,50 0,100"/>
  <polygon id="right" points="100,0 50,50 100,100"/>
  <polygon id="down" points="0,100 50,50 100,100"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
svg { position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0 }
polygon { fill: transparent; }
#left {
    cursor: url(http://www.thisisfed.com/img/extra/cursors/left.png), auto;
    z-index: 10003;
}
#right {
    cursor: url(http://www.thisisfed.com/img/extra/cursors/right.png), auto;
    z-index: 10003;
}
#up {
    cursor: url(http://www.thisisfed.com/img/extra/cursors/up.png), auto;
    z-index: 10003;
}
#down {
    cursor: url(http://www.thisisfed.com/img/extra/cursors/down.png), auto;
    z-index: 10003;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cabs2975/2/)